# binding itemscontrol to list which is a property in parent's datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i'm a WPF noob .
iv'e got a **listbox**  which is bound to a Property of class **Client**

```
public class Client : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Player> peers ;
    public List<Player> Peers 
    {
        get { return peers; }
        set
        {
            peers = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Peers"));
        }
    }
}
```

the listbox parent's datacontext is bound to a Client instance

```
  GameDetailsPanel.DataContext = client;
```

the listbox is bounded as follows :

```
 <ListBox.Items>
     <Binding Path="Peers"></Binding>
 </ListBox.Items>
```

to my understanding this is suppose to bound the list to the path relative to it's parent's
datacontext .. when i run the application i get the following error:

```
   {"A 'Binding' cannot be used within a 'ItemCollection' collection. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."}
```

any ideas what i'm doing wrong .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `ItemsSource` to your `List` of `Players`.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Peers}">
 </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

o'k i found out what i was doing wrong 
normally i would dismiss this question .. but maybe it could help out a noob like me 
some day ..so

```
             <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                  <Binding Path="Peers"></Binding>
             </ListBox.ItemsSource>
```